# How to load image thumbnail from sdcard android?

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

hi there i have got a sample code from Developer.android.com and it fetches image from webpage with specified url and for thumbnail also it fetches url from the same page,
here is the sample code.

```
public class Images {
public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {
           "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s1024/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg", };

public final static String[] imageThumbUrls = new String[] {
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s160-c/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s160-c/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg", };
```

here they use url to fetch the image from a webpage and dislpaying instead i have to show image from sdcard.

thank you can i edit the code for sdcard images.

Answer (score 1):

You able to show image from sdcard to webview .

Here is code sample.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/test.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

you need to append the"prefix "file://" before any file so as to display in the webview.

Comment: Hi @Md Abdul it dont need it from a webview no need of html response just i have to show thumbnail of images from sdcard without accesing gallery thumbnail.

Comment: you want to show image thumbnail , like android default photo Gallery.

Comment: yes but not from the default gallery thumbnail of android i have to create my own thumbnail folder, and i created it while processing it the thumbnail loads too slow is there any code to make it load fast.

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader . it load image in background.